# uploading csv file using jquery ajax and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

here i want upload and move the csv file using jquery ajax function.

```
$("#file").change(function() { 
  alert($("#file").val());
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Task_controller/upload_tasksquestion",
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: {file: $("#file").val()},
    success: function(text) {
        alert(text);
        if(text == "success") {
            alert("Your image was uploaded successfully");
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("An error occured, please try again.");         
    }
  });   
});
```

and my html code is:

```
< input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file">
```

and i am testing in controller function uploaded file name
like $this->input->post('file');

but it is not come to the controller and i want to move that file into a folder.
please help me where i am doing mistake...

my server side code is:

```
$curdate=date('Y-m-d');
$path='./assets/fileuploads/';
$file=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $file);
$actual_file_name = time().substr($txt, 5).".".$ext;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path.$actual_file_name))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) to send files over via AJAX.

Store the file in a FormData object and pass the object as your `data`.

```
$("#file").change(function() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', this.files[0]); // since this is your file input

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Task_controller/upload_tasksquestion",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // important
        contentType: false, // important
        data: fd,
        success: function(text) {
            alert(text);
            if(text == "success") {
                alert("Your image was uploaded successfully");
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occured, please try again.");         
        }
    });
});
```

Read [File Uploading Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller) (particularly from The Controller section) on how to deal with the file on the server-side end.

Comment: any need to add upload library? in serverside? because i am testing but it always says error occurs.Please help.

Comment: According to instructions, you need to load the `Upload` library. Edit your question with the relevant server-side code. Error can mean many things. Open your browser developer tools, find the Network panel that shows all your AJAX requests, and find the actual message that is being given for error.

Comment: it is my server side code :       $config['upload_path']          =          './assets/fileuploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = '.csv/.CSV';
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  
  echo $this->upload->do_upload('fd');            here just i want to know the uploaded file name.