# How to Submit or POST a Csv file using Ajax along with other form details

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

There is a HTML form having input fields Name, Location, Address, Family members(Csv to be uploaded) and a Submit button. But when clicked on submit, Csv file data is not being passed to the php. Below is the code for reference,

```js
var formData = new FormData($('.AdvFrm')[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    method: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: formData.serialize(),
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with that (although `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'` is nonsense). You need to provide a [mcve] (including the HTML for the form) and more information about how you are testing for the CSV data on the server.

Comment: does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874303/uploading-csv-file-using-jquery-ajax-and-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you put your data in a FormData part then serialize it? It should return error because there is no `serialize` method of FormData.

I guess that you've just changed it from jQuery serialize object to FormData in the first line.

And in your case, all you need to do is change `formData.serialize()` to `formData`

```
var formData = new FormData($('.AdvFrm')[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    method: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

If you your formData object is not contains the detail you should add it like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var file = $('#file').val(); // Remember to put an id to your file <input type="file" id="file" />
formData.append('file', file);
```